# Default image size not working

Tags: theme-development, images, hooks, bug

I have some hooks on my WordPress Theme in order to customize the default images sizes, but it does not work. Here is the code:

```
function my_custom_image_size() {
    add_image_size( 'post_size', 730);
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_custom_image_size' );

// Cambia el nombre del tamano de imagen
function my_custom_image_size_name( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'post_size' => __( 'Tamaño Post' ),
    ) );
}
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_image_size_name' );

function my_default_image_size() {
    update_option('image_default_size', 'post_size');
    update_option('image_default_align', 'right');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_default_image_size');

function my_remove_default_images( $sizes ) {
    unset($sizes['thumbnail']); // disable thumbnail size 
    unset($sizes['medium']); // disable medium size 
    unset($sizes['large']); // disable large size 
    unset($sizes['medium_large']); // disable medium-large size 
    unset($sizes['1536x1536']); // disable 2x medium-large size 
    unset($sizes['2048x2048']); // disable 2x large size return $sizes;
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'my_remove_default_images' );
```

Everything works fine but the function "my_default_image_size" does not work I don't know why.
Any of these lines of code works:

```
update_option('image_default_size', 'post_size');
update_option('image_default_align', 'right');
```

When I go to a new post, the default image size is full-size and the default alignment is center.
It seems a bug on "image_default_size" and "image_default_align"

When I add a new image in the sidebar appears like that:

[image: Default option, Fullsize]

---

[image: Options]

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there are spaces at the end of the option names:

```
update_option('image_default_size ', 'post_size');
update_option('image_default_align ', 'right');
```

it should be:

```
update_option('image_default_size', 'post_size');
update_option('image_default_align', 'right');
```

Comment: Hi rugbert, thanks for your answer. Onfortunately it was a mistake but I fixe it and the problem continues. I am thinking about the `image_default_size` works only with default size names... thumbnail, medium, large, etc...

But... the `image_default_align` it should work.